# How to create an Outlook calendar entry each time a workbook is saved?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'd like to create an Outlook calendar meeting request each time a workbook is saved.

The meeting requests need to be added to a shared mailbox so that all users that have access see the meeting invite.

So far it adds an entry to my personal calendar.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2021") 'define your sheet!
  
    Dim olApp As Object  'create outlook application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNS As Object 'get namespace
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'define constants if using late binding
    Const olFolderCalendar As Long = 9
    Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1

    Dim olRecItems As Object 'get all appointments
    Set olRecItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    Dim strFilter As String  'filter for appointments
    Dim olFilterRecItems As Object 'filtered appointments

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 3

    Do Until Trim$(ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value) = vbNullString
        'filter appointments for subject
        strFilter = "[Subject] = '" & Trim$(ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value) & "'"
        Set olFilterRecItems = olRecItems.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

        If olFilterRecItems.Count = 0 Then 'if subject does not exist
            With olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                .Subject = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
                .Start = ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
                .AllDayEvent = True
                .BusyStatus = 5
                .ReminderSet = True
                .Save
            End With
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        End If

        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Update:

I managed to get this. The problem now is that it'll only create the calendar entry for the last line.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2020") 'define your sheet!
  
    Dim olApp As Object  'create outlook application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNS As Object 'get namespace
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim myRequiredAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
        
    'define constants if using late binding
    Const olFolderCalendar As Long = 9
    Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1

    Dim olRecItems As Object 'get all appointments
    Set olRecItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
        
    Set olAppItem = olRecItems.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    Dim strFilter As String  'filter for appointments
    Dim olFilterRecItems As Object 'filtered appointments

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 3

    Do Until Trim$(ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value) = vbNullString
        'filter appointments for subject
        strFilter = "[Subject] = '" & Trim$(ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value) & "'"
        Set olFilterRecItems = olRecItems.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

        If olFilterRecItems.Count = 0 Then 'if subject does not exist
            With olAppItem
            Set myRequiredAttendee = .Recipients.Add("email address")
            myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired
                .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30
                .Subject = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
                .Start = ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
                .AllDayEvent = True
                .BusyStatus = 5
                .ReminderSet = True
                .Send
            End With
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        End If

        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following code:

```
Dim olRecItems As Object 'get all appointments
Set olRecItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
```

You need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
 Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Eugene, many thanks for the response. I was wondering if you could factor that into my code at all? I'm not too knowledgeable with VBA so I'm not entirely sure what to remove and add from my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only you knows the recipient who has shared the calendar. The sample code illustrates the code which should be changed.

Comment: ahh sorry, I mean it just needs to go create an appointment in one of calendars I have listed under "All Group Calendars" > "Helpdesk Support". Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey Eugene, I've tried to amend the code but I don't really know where to add those changes. Can you help further please?

Comment: You can try iterating over all folders to find the required one if it is not shared one. For example, you may use the `Parent` property to get the parent folder and use the `Folders` to get the subfolders collection.

Comment: Hey Eugene, not entirely sure I follow. Apologies, I'm not familiar with VBA in the slightest really. I'd just love to be able to get this working to help our team. So far the code simply adds a record to my personal calendar once it's been saved. Also, in the process of saving it turns the field green to signify the addition. All I'm trying to do is simply manipulate this code to send this calendar entry to a shared mailbox\calendar called 'Helpdesk Support'. Another alterative, if it's easier might be to send to multiple user addresses instead. Would you be able to help me draft this out?

Comment: You can use the `Recipients.Add` method to add multiple recipients.

Comment: Yes that would work also, where about's would I add that? Can I just simply add that to my existing code for it to work?

Comment: Hey Eugene, are you able to provide any more assistance by any chance? Many thanks

Comment: I am happy to help. But you need to have some programming knowledge to apply any help. SO is not for requesting ready-made solutions.

Comment: It seems you were managed to add it to the code. I'd suggest asking separate question in new threads, so you users could distinguish questions and answers.